# How a human brain does computation after lexical analysis and parsing?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, neural-computing

I've been trying to figure out the answer for this question.

> How exactly a human brain understands or computes the meaning of any sentence after doing the lexical analysis and parsing? What is the science behind this?

I've searched widely but couldn't read anything satisfactorily. I hope to get one here! Beside, It will be helpful if someone could also suggest me some resources where i can learn more about this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer - nobody knows, though some people (indeed, several disciplines) think that they know a tiny little bit.

Comment: This is far too broad a question for Stack Exchange. One could spend a whole research career on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a tiny bit I **know** there is flaw in the question to start with.
These are connected and "understanding" process starts with the first word. Interconnecting everything to provide one satisfactory answer is impossible.
If you are really interested in subject read history of H&M and Phineas Cage.
Then start with the core point of problem stated with simpler question "why people do not remember anything before they were 3 years old" approximatelly 3, but you will find out soon enough.
Then read about Cohort model.

Sorry but I do not have several days to spare right now.
And probably this is not ontopic here.